# Filtering 'unanswered' shows answered questions

Tags: bug

I filtered the questions by 'unanswered', and went to the last page, hoping to find some 'comment-answers' to community wiki.

To my surprise, I found there were questions with lots of (generally around five) answers, although there are only (currently) 300 pages - much less than the 5764 questions in total. [*Try it here*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?page=300&sort=unanswered&pagesize=15)<sup>1</sup>.

What is happening here? which questions are being filtered out, if some with answers are still included?

<sup>1</sup><sub>Mobile version (not app) if that helps.</sub>

Comment: It's a somewhat misleading name but there was resistance on Meta SE when someone suggested renaming it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153462/the-title-of-the-unanswered-questions-page-seems-a-bit-misleading I guess we're just stuck with it (unrelatedly, my pet peeve about misleading names is that "favorites" are apparently supposed to also serve as bookmarks, so there's no way to tell if someone "favoriting" a post means that they like it, or just that they want to come back to it later for some other reason)

Comment: Don't answers need to have nonnegative votes to be considered answers for that queue?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I had a quick search, but that question didn't come up.